# Get count of similar values in a comma separated column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Hi I would like to get the count of similar values in a mysql column for example, I have to get ***count of '10'*** from ***product_id('9,10,9,10,9,10')*** and its result should be like ***'3'*** using MySQL. Is there a way to do that

Comment: one does not store comma separated values in columns

Comment: Unfortunately it was stored that way.

Comment: well then it's not too late to correct it

Comment: ... and the column name `product_id` hints to an even deeper design horror beyond.

Comment: it is not a primary/ foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JaydipJ has the right idea but a safer method is:

```
SET @str = '9,10,9,10,9,10';
SET @tofind = '10'

SELECT (LENGTH(CONCAT(',', @str, ',') - 
        LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(',', @str, ','),
                       CONCAT(',', @tofind, ','
                            ), ''
                      )
              )
       ) / LENGTH(@tofind)
```

This should return the correct result if the string contains 101 or 101010.

As mentioned in the comments.  Storing lists in SQL in a comma-delimited list is a bad idea.  Such string manipulation would typically be done in a more appropriate language.

Comment: Can this be achieved better with `full text search`? Just asking

Comment: @Shaharyar . . . Not with this data. Numbers are usually filtered out of full-text indexes (by default).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that column have value `'9,10,9,10,9,10'`  and search string is two digit then you can find occurrence like this

```
SELECT (LENGTH('9,10,9,10,9,10') - LENGTH(REPLACE('9,10,9,10,9,10','10','')) ) / LENGTH('10')
```

Comment: it can be of any number of digits